# CakePHP: To Create A New Controller

Tags: cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.0.5 (but this isn't necessarily a cakephp specific question). I have a Coupon and a User model. Each time a user prints a coupon (proccessed by: Coupon Controller):

```
class CouponsController extends AppController {
    public function printcoupon($id = null) {
        // code
    }
}
```

I want to save the information to a "coupons_printed" table (id/coupon_id/user_id/created). Should I create a new model for this, or should I just create a function inside of the Coupon model similar to (and call it in the controller each time that page is viewed)?:

```
class Coupon extends AppModel {
    function insertIntoPrinted($id) { 
        $this->query("UPDATE coupons_printed SET .....");  
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you do, a raw SQL query is *not* the best way to go. Always use CakePHP methods if at all possible (and almost always it *is* possible).

You should put the `insertIntoPrinted()` function in the CouponsPrinted model (although, as a side note, PrintedCoupon would be a more natural way to name the model...) You can then add a HasMany relationship to the Coupon model (`$hasMany = array( 'CouponsPrinted' )`) and call the function in the CouponsController:

```
public function printcoupon($id = null) {
    $this->Coupon->CouponsPrinted->insertIntoPrinted( $id );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP's model has a thing call association.
In your case, Coupon has a hasMany association with coupons_printed.
You can create a new model, or query using the association in the Coupon model, the generated queries will be the same, I believe.

Your CouponsController already depend on Coupon Model, so not creating another model is a better solution.